# Relationship between return keyword and finally keyword in c#

Tags: c#, exception

i want to find out that the relationship between "return" and "finally" keywords. what is the execution order and what happens when exception occurs and return keyword is called after code block does some stuff, if there is two nested finally blocks as shown below,

```
        try
        {
            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //do some stuff
                return;
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        finally
        {

        }
```

Comment: Why don't you open a C# project and just try? You already have the code.

Comment: Both finallys will be executed, starting from the innermost to the outermost.

Comment: They have no relationship

Comment: There is a relationship, and if you do not know this basic principle, please do not comment questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Typically, the statements of a **finally** block are executed when control leaves a try statement, whether the transfer of control occurs as a result of normal execution, of execution of a **break**, **continue**, **goto**, or **return** statement, or of propagation of an **exception** out of the try statement.

In your example, both `finally` blocks will execute.  The inner one will execute first, and then the outer finally will execute.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It seems to be a correct answer.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering the same thing.

Comment: i accidentally downvote. This is the correct answer as you said

Answer (score 1):

No matter what happens, **finally** block is going to be executed.
As far as **return** is concerned, if a **try** block contains a **return**, it will actually do something like storing it in some variable, and return it at the end, after the execution of the finally block. like this:

```
try{
    return xyz; //(i.e, temp = xyz;)
    }
catch() {}
finally {}
return temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

`finally` means run this code *whatever* happens

*whatever* could mean `return` or `catch`

Answer (score 0):

Finally always gets executed. Whether you get exception or not your finally block will execute. And in your case both of your finall blocks will get executed.

Answer (score 0):

If some error occurs in the inner try block, the control would goto the inner catch block, then the inner finally , then outer finally and then return the value that you did in the inner catch block.

Try debugging the code and you will get the flow

Answer (score 0):

The finally block will always execute even in case of exception also. To understand consider below code

```
    try
    {
    //sql connection opened
    //execute a query ----> EXCEPTION OCCURRED HERE 

//return the result
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
    throw ex;
    }
    finally{
    //close the connection
    }
```

above is the code that demonstrates widely used scenario of finally block. The connection to the database has to be closed even if exception occurs while executing the query.

If there is no exception then also the finally block will execute and then will return the result